# Why is data security genuine technically not perfectly possible?

Tags: legal, data-leakage

**Why is data security genuine technically not perfectly possible?**

In my country (Austria) I was a member of the team that made first laws for protecting "person-related data" for every person.

Have we to fear new, too big uncertainties?

Comment: This is pretty subjective an opinion based. Also, what is your question?

Comment: you are right, I changed my question....wbr

Comment: you still need to ask a specific question.

Comment: You seem to be asking why very few judgements have been passed regarding data protection violations in Austria? Is that correct? If so, could you edit your question above and clarify what you're asking and what you're not asking? There are a number of reasons I could think of (lack of dual IT-law expertise compared to volume of attacks, high difficulty of identifying offenders so they can be prosecuted, lack of competent investigators?).

Comment: The kernel problem in Austria is that we have all laws which are necessary but nearly nobody uses them. I want to know if other countries of even state-communities have same problems. Most national laws loose their validity when international data actions are given.

Comment: We have laws that say people can't steal from your house. But you still lock your front door in case someone doesn't follow the law. Exactly the same for data security.

Comment: When you say "laws for protecting the personal data of every person", you mean protecting against hackers (stealing a database content for instance), or protecting against illegal usage or collection by a legitimate company?

Comment: No, "personally related data" are data like name, address, birthdate, private habits).

Comment: The problems is that laws exist, but only on national level and no one between the states and continents for instance between Europe and USA or Canada.

Comment: I have change my question, please react......

Comment: You still haven't asked a cohesive question. "What to do" about what? What about regulatory standards like PCI-DSS, HIPAA, etc.?

Comment: I suppose you refer to the [Federal Act Concerning the Protection of Personal Data (Datenschutzgesetz 2000)](http://www.dataprotection.eu/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.AT), in force since January 2000, starting with this nice statement "*Everybody shall have the right to secrecy for the personal data concerning him, especially with regard to his private and family life, insofar as he has an interest deserving such protection*", nice sentence especially in this period where a lot of states are are actually voting "anti-privacy" laws for the sake of security.

Comment: Personally I do not expect concrete international agreement on such subject soon because there are too much opposite interests. However, I do not know if in Austria the [GDB](https://www.dsb.gv.at) is as active than the French [CNIL](http://www.cnil.fr) since here, this organism is really involved into communicating in a way reachable by a large audience (website, press, associations, etc.) about right and wrong things happening about personal data threats, measures to adopt, and it is the main point of contact reachable by any individual having a concern with such topic.

Comment: The closure of this question shows that there is no interest on international level to come to an worldwide satisfying result. Lets hope for next decades...

Comment: I have edited my question- it was realy a mixture of too much. I hope now it's one clear question.

Answer (score 2):

Laws are meant to provide protection to the general populace from criminal elements (in theory, at least-- I'm not going to debate here if most laws are meant to protect the commoner or those with the most power and/or money or other factors). We have laws so they can act as a deterrent to criminal behavior and help maintain order in society. This is true for every society in the world, to some extent.

If a hacker breaks into a database, acquires millions of credit card numbers, and then disseminates this information in a data dump, there has to be a law in place to punish the hacker, so they can be placed in jail, both as a means of keeping the criminal element at bay, as well as a deterrent to others that might try the same thing. If there's no law, the hacker goes free to commit other morally indecent acts.

So, technology provides a deterrent in the form of physical and/or logical protection from destruction or theft, and laws provide a deterrent in the form of a threat of financial loss and/or a loss of freedom (prison time). As long as the laws are not overbearing to the point where technology and innovation suffers, and as long as the technology doesn't deter legitimate use of the data, the use of both will prevent casual violations of personal data while still allowing the data to be useful.

Of course, there's always people that are willing to take the chances needed to get to the data, knowing the repercussions of doing so, and are intelligent enough to circumvent the technology that defends that data. However, if the technology is significantly strong enough, that will narrow down the number of people that are willing *and* able to obtain and/or abuse the data. Laws nor technology can completely eliminate the possibility of someone intelligent, skilled, and determined enough to get at the data.

Technology provides the means of prevention, while laws provide the means of mitigation. However, technology should be as strong as possible, while laws should provide only enough deterrent effect to convince morally gray people to not do something without stifling innovation. Prevention is preferential to mitigation.